# How to Programmatically Tell How Much Memory an iOS App is Using?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, memory, memory-management

Anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: actually there are ways to find out how much memory is still available, if that help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579642/monitor-memory-usage-in-an-iphone-app

Comment: This is not a dupe. The questions are clearly different. How much is free != how much is used.

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate.