# Understanding the effects on retain count of methods other than retain and release

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a routine to correctly allocate and deallocate my `UIView` subclass, but when I set a break point in the class's `- (void) dealloc`, I see that it is not called and I that have a huge memory leak.

So I print the `retainCount` before the release and it is 2 (this could be normal, because other objects can use it). I searched and do not see any other `retain` messages. Then I send:

```
[myObject removeFromSuperview];
```

And now it is deallocated. Which makes me realize that earlier I sent:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myObject];
```

It is VERY DIFFICULT know that when I use `bringSubviewToFront:`, I always have to call `removeFromSuperview`. Do there exist other methods like this that can increase the retain count?

If this object weren't a subclass, and was only a `UIView`, I would've never known that I had created a memory leak.

So, how can I really know that my objects have been released and that the memory is free?

It isn't important for me to know what is happening, but I want to know that I am creating and removing the object. Here's a demonstration that the same code with and without the `removeFromSuperview` can cause the effects I'm seeing -- this is my log.

When I do **not** use `removeFromSuperview`,

```
Memory used 16687.1 ( +5378), free 262213.6 kb
Memory used 19451.9 ( +2765), free 257159.2 kb
Memory used 19451.9 (    +0), free 259530.8 kb 
Memory used 21844.0 ( +2392), free 257830.9 kb 
Memory used 24313.9 ( +2470), free 256356.4 kb 
Memory used 25260.0 (  +946), free 253141.0 kb
Memory used 27848.7 ( +2589), free 252874.8 kb
Memory used 30142.5 ( +2294), free 250814.5 kb
Memory used 30814.2 (  +672), free 247787.5 kb
```

you can see the memory usage only increases, but when I **do** use it:

```
Memory used 16105.5 ( +4829), free 262619.1 kb
Memory used 16527.4 (  +422), free 262815.8 kb
Memory used 14168.1 ( -2359), free 262832.1 kb
Memory used 16769.0 ( +2601), free 263266.3 kb
Memory used 16560.1 (  -209), free 264785.9 kb 
Memory used 14200.8 ( -2359), free 264794.1 kb 
Memory used 16789.5 ( +2589), free 264290.3 kb 
Memory used 16597.0 (  -193), free 264499.2 kb 
Memory used 14237.7 ( -2359), free 264515.6 kb 
Memory used 16609.3 ( +2372), free 264290.3 kb 
Memory used 16560.1 (   -49), free 264425.5 kb 
Memory used 14200.8 ( -2359), free 264441.8 kb
```

now the memory increases and decreases like I want.

I got the code to log the memory usage from https://stackoverflow.com/q/7990532/632472.

Comment: lol.. I have some problems with English grammar :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing something like this?

```
self.subView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

If so, that might be your issue.  The retain count will be 2.  Once for the alloc, and once for the property set.  You might want to consider adding a call to autorelease

```
self.subView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement that you call `removeFromSuperview` after calling `bringSubviewToFront:`. There is only a requirement that you release what you retain. `removeFromSuperview` is called when you want to remove a view from its view hierarchy. That it also calls `release` is irrelevant.

More likely here you have some other over-retain of `myObject`. Are you always using accessors for your ivars? Direct access of ivars (except in init and dealloc) are the most common cause of memory leaks. If `myObject` isn't stored in an ivar, then run the analyzer to make sure you're not over-retaining `myObject` somewhere more obvious. (The analyzer is bad about understanding ivars, but using accessors generally fixes those problems.)

Comment: I edit the post and put some data. Because I saw this I concluded I have to call `removeFromSuperView`

Comment: I'm not saying you don't have a leak. I'm saying that the removeFromSuperview is likely masking the leak. Your leak is more likely elsewhere. @dar512 has a good example of a possible leak.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that somewhere at your code you are adding that object to the view with something like that:

```
[self.view addSubview:myObject];
```

If so, that's the point of additional retain, as any UIView retains it's content. Actually call to

```
[myObject removeFromSuperView];
```

does the release magic for you...