# Watching memory usage in MonoTouch App

Tags: ios, memory, xamarin.ios

How can I find out how much memory my App is using from inside the app itself, using MonoTouch?

I basically want this:

[Watching memory usage in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989864/watching-memory-usage-in-ios)

which calls things like "task_info"

but for MonoTouch (it's OK if works only on iOS). I don't want a memory tool, like Instruments, etc, I just want to know the memory used from inside the App itself, so I can display it and be able to check it isn't too much in various field trials, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two options:

- Copy the "task_info" code into a new Xcode project and create a static library out of it. Then you link with that static library in your MonoTouch project, and use a P/Invoke to call logMemUsage.
- Translate all the "task_info" code into C# (using P/Invokes to call native methods whenever required).

I would likely go for the first option, I believe it's somewhat less error prone.

Comment: Thanks, I'm hoping someone will do this for me ;)

Comment: How about using GC.GetTotalMemory(). Is this a reasonable measure of the memory being used by an iOS app? It seems to give values a bit different to Instruments.

Comment: @Bbx: GC.GetTotalMemory () will only report the managed memory used by Xamarin.iOS, it will not report any memory in use by iOS itself.