# How to get the memory usage of a process in Mac OS (and in iOS)?

Tags: ios, macos, memory, usage-statistics, procfs

In Linux, the kernel exposes various per-process memory counters through /proc/[pid]/statm including

- total program size
- resident set size
- shared pages
- text (code)
- data/stack
- library
- dirty pages

What is the equivalent of such thing in Mac OS (and iOS)? I am aware of the sysctl interface, but it does not appear to provide the equivalent information.

I have looked at the "top" output (invoked by non-root user) on Mac OS and it contains things like

- RPRVT - amount of resident memory consumed by our heap allocations
- RSHRD - amount of resident shared memory (shared libraries)
- RSIZE - ~equals RPRVT + RSHRD
- VSIZE - the total amount of memory consumed by the process (resident and paged mem combined)

I wonder where such information is retrieved. Are there any additional counters (similar to the Linux ones) that are not displayed by top.

What about iOS?

EDIT: note that I'm looking for the per-process memory usage counter (not global system ones)

Thanks!

Comment: Instruments + activity monitor?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7990532/1693173)

Comment: To Justin Meiners: I do not have root and cannot do any instrumentation of other apps.

Comment: To progrmr: I am not only interested in the memory usage of my own process, but also other processes running in the system