# IOS process internals - how to get information?

Tags: objective-c, c, ios4

I am looking for an API to monitor the tasks running on a plain iPhone (no jailbreak). Those are about:

- **look for CPU usage** (my main concern).
- look for memory usage.
- look for disk usage (how many read/write)
- look for network usage (how many bytes sent and received by network: 3G, Wifi, GSM).
- is it possible to rely on the IOS simulator running on a Mac (or should I test my application directly on the device)?

I think I can look into the system C libraries (sigint, etc.) but I am not sure to be able to retrieve this information except for the current applications running. I know some monitor applications run on the global usage but I would like to be able to find the information process by process.

If someone can provide some links or something useful, I will start a deeper investigation then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CPU usage can be found by looking at the code from this related question:

[iOS - Get CPU usage from application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223348/ios-get-cpu-usage-from-application)

Memory usage:

[Available memory for iPhone OS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798638/available-memory-for-iphone-os-app/2798771)

And here are a couple threads that talk about how to find out about the applications or tasks currently running:

[Can we retrieve the applications currently running in iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312613/can-we-retrieve-the-applications-currently-running-in-iphone-and-ipad)

[How to get information about free memory and running processes in an App Store approved app? (Yes, there is one!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275578/how-to-get-information-about-free-memory-and-running-processes-in-an-app-store-a)

[How to get the active processes running in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342578/how-to-get-the-active-processes-running-in-ios)

The answers to these questions may point you in the direction you'd like to head towards.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I looked at the links and pushed the code into my application. It confirms what I was pretty sure: there is no way to have _detailed_ information about the programs. I can retrieve the process names and priority but not their CPU usage (at least for a normal iPhone). For the current task, I can get some detailed information, sure I can do this globally too (how many memory still there) but not process by process. I suppose this is related to the _sandbox_ application space and to avoid to spy the performances of the other applications.

Comment: before I attempt to answer your question further, is this for an in-house app, a jailbroken app, or an app you want to sell on the app store?

Comment: As explained, it is for a non-jailbroken iPhone. And, at the end for an In-House application (not be sold in the App Store).

Comment: Even not answering my question, this response is very complete. As I tested and understood, the applications are sandboxed and then it is not possible to observe the CPU usage of other applications running on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

The [Activity Monitor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/PerformanceTools/PerformanceTools.html) should get you what you're looking for. You should be able to observe RAM, CPU, and VRAM usage for each iOS process. This is a default tool installed with xCode. Very handy.

Comment: Sure. But my question was: how to get this stuff inside an iPhone application (watching for other applications running on the same device).