# How to get the active processes running in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, system

How do I programmatically get the active processes running in the background, CPU and RAM usage for iOS?

Comment: Use sysctl. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312613/can-we-retrieve-the-applications-currently-running-in-iphone-and-ipad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPU usage was retrieved here: [iOS - Get CPU usage from application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223348/ios-get-cpu-usage-from-application)

RAM usage seems to be addressed here: [Available memory for iPhone OS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798638/available-memory-for-iphone-os-app/2798771)

Edit:

Like EricS has pointed out in comments, there seems to be a way to get background tasks: [Can we retrieve the applications currently running in iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312613/can-we-retrieve-the-applications-currently-running-in-iphone-and-ipad) and [How to get information about free memory and running processes in an App Store approved app? (Yes, there is one!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275578/how-to-get-information-about-free-memory-and-running-processes-in-an-app-store-a)

Answer (score 5):

The code self-explain :)

```
#import <mach/mach.h>
#import <mach/mach_host.h>
#import <sys/sysctl.h>
- (NSArray *)runningProcesses {

    int mib[4] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0};
    size_t miblen = 4;

    size_t size;
    int st = sysctl(mib, miblen, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);

    struct kinfo_proc * process = NULL;
    struct kinfo_proc * newprocess = NULL;

    do {

        size += size / 10;
        newprocess = realloc(process, size);

        if (!newprocess){

            if (process){
                free(process);
            }

            return nil;
        }

        process = newprocess;
        st = sysctl(mib, miblen, process, &size, NULL, 0);

    } while (st == -1 && errno == ENOMEM);

    if (st == 0){

        if (size % sizeof(struct kinfo_proc) == 0){
            int nprocess = size / sizeof(struct kinfo_proc);

            if (nprocess){

                NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                for (int i = nprocess - 1; i >= 0; i--){

                    NSString * processID = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", process[i].kp_proc.p_pid];
                    NSString * processName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", process[i].kp_proc.p_comm];

                    NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:processID, processName, nil]
                                                                        forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ProcessID", @"ProcessName", nil]];
                    [array addObject:dict];
                }

                free(process);
                return array;
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: sysctl is always return 0 in iOS9.