# How to get all process info in objective-c under iOS system?

Tags: ios, macos, process

Under Mac OS, i could use GetCurrentProcess and GetNextProcessInfo to get  process infos. But when i use the functions under iOS system,i got the link errorslike:

Undefined symbols for architechture i386： “_GetCurrentProcess” "_GetProcessInformation"....

How to get all process info in objective-c under iOS system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is no `GetCurrentProcess` or `GetProcessInformation` calls on iOS as Apple would prefer that each application live in it's own "sandbox" and know nothing about other apps running on the phone.

But there may be ways to approximate what you are trying to do.

Here are a few related questions that may help you out:

[Can we retrieve the applications currently running in iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312613/can-we-retrieve-the-applications-currently-running-in-iphone-and-ipad)

[How to get information about free memory and running processes in an App Store approved app? (Yes, there is one!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275578/how-to-get-information-about-free-memory-and-running-processes-in-an-app-store-a)

[How to get the active processes running in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342578/how-to-get-the-active-processes-running-in-ios)

The answers to these questions may point you in the direction you'd like to head towards.

Good luck!