# Get all threads belonging to a process

Tags: swift, linux, multithreading, macos

Python has a method called `threading.enumerate()` that returns all threads belonging to a process. How can this be done in Swift (on macOS/Linux)? I want to get an `Array` of `String`s that belongs to the process, regardless of wether I created it or a library created it.

The kinds of threads that I want are those that will be shown when I execute `ps -T`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all process info in objective-c under iOS system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886217/how-to-get-all-process-info-in-objective-c-under-ios-system)

Comment: There are POSIX threads, (NS)Thread, dispatch queues ... what exactly do you need?

Comment: @MartinR Threads that will appear when I run `ps -T` is what I want.

Comment: @FyodorVolchyok Objective C != Swift. By the way, I am using MacOS.

Comment: Do I guess correctly that you are asking about Linux? – That would be an important information to add to the question (and tags).

Comment: @MartinR yes I want it to work on macOS/Linux, sorry for the confusion