# How to find the itunes application name for the running process name in iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes

I want to find the itunes application name for the running processes name in iPhone.Because my application name is different from itunes application name.For example my application name is abc plus.But bundle display name is abc +.

My application is iPhone application, In this bundle display name is different from product name.

In my project I am collecting running processes in iPhone and I want to replace running applications name with the itunes application name for all the processes.

If anybody doesnt understood the question they can ask.Please dont give negtive marks.

Comment: anybody please reply me i need the soultion.... If any correct answer is given they will get good compliment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the Music app starts a few processes, these are definitely from iTunes:

- Music~iphone
- itunescloudd

Found them like this:

- Kill all apps (double home button and hold an app icon)
- I used the Carat app to get the process list
- Start the music app
- See what processes appeared in the Carat app :)

Comment: Gentleman I am telling about using sysctl i will get the running apps in iphone programatically, i dont want process names i want itunes display names for all the processes running in iPhone.

Comment: And what about using the same strategy? Closing all possible processes, get the process list. Then start the Music player and compare the 2 lists?

Comment: I tried like running application and collecting running apps and then playing music and then collecting running apps, but there is not much difference.All the apps are having same name,Even the application i am testing through is ABC Plus, but bundle display name is ABC +.But it always shows ABC Plus,I want ABC +.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I can't help you further.

Comment: I found this solution to get the IDs then finding the application name in itunes using JSON. For reference I have this link, it may be helpful to you guys.http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Comment: And this is the url will give every thing about running processes and cpu information   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342578/how-to-get-the-active-processes-running-in-ios

Comment: but still i am not sure how to get the itunes application name? any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Your question leads to a really interesting fact: **The process "Music~iphone" isn't started only if you hear music – it's started, too if you make a search with Google app or any other Google app like Maps – even if you've never heard any music !!**

And it won't be killed in the background. So whenever you're searching for something with Google (app) or any other Google app like Maps there starts this process in the background until it's actively killed or your iPhone is rebooted – and it uses your resources. This is consistently reproducable on all my iPhones – and different iOS versions (5.1.1 latest).

I don't like that at all and will investigate further…