# How to get notification when CPU usage goes beyond certain point?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications

I want to get notification whenever my application CPU usage goes to certain level.
I can then print all logs and find out whats going wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - Get CPU usage from application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223348/ios-get-cpu-usage-from-application)

Comment: Its not duplicate. I don't want to monitor the CPU change myself. I want to get callback when it goes beyond certain point.

Answer (score 0):

May be the following links will help you-

[Get CPU percent usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785069/get-cpu-percent-usage)

[iOS - Get CPU usage from application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223348/ios-get-cpu-usage-from-application)

[How to get the active processes running in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342578/how-to-get-the-active-processes-running-in-ios)

And after getting CPU uses you can find desired point.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223348/ios-get-cpu-usage-from-application)

```
- (float)cpuUsages
{
    kern_return_t kr;
    task_info_data_t tinfo;
    mach_msg_type_number_t task_info_count;

    task_info_count = TASK_INFO_MAX;
    kr = task_info(mach_task_self(), TASK_BASIC_INFO, (task_info_t)tinfo, &task_info_count);
    if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        return -1;
    }

    task_basic_info_t      basic_info;
    thread_array_t         thread_list;
    mach_msg_type_number_t thread_count;

    thread_info_data_t     thinfo;
    mach_msg_type_number_t thread_info_count;

    thread_basic_info_t basic_info_th;
    uint32_t stat_thread = 0; // Mach threads

    basic_info = (task_basic_info_t)tinfo;

    // get threads in the task
    kr = task_threads(mach_task_self(), &thread_list, &thread_count);
    if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (thread_count > 0)
        stat_thread += thread_count;

    long tot_sec = 0;
    long tot_usec = 0;
    float tot_cpu = 0;
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < thread_count; j++)
    {
        thread_info_count = THREAD_INFO_MAX;
        kr = thread_info(thread_list[j], THREAD_BASIC_INFO,
                         (thread_info_t)thinfo, &thread_info_count);
        if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) {
            return -1;
        }

        basic_info_th = (thread_basic_info_t)thinfo;

        if (!(basic_info_th->flags & TH_FLAGS_IDLE)) {
            tot_sec = tot_sec + basic_info_th->user_time.seconds + basic_info_th->system_time.seconds;
            tot_usec = tot_usec + basic_info_th->system_time.microseconds + basic_info_th->system_time.microseconds;
            tot_cpu = tot_cpu + basic_info_th->cpu_usage / (float)TH_USAGE_SCALE * 100.0;
        }

    } // for each thread

    kr = vm_deallocate(mach_task_self(), (vm_offset_t)thread_list, thread_count * sizeof(thread_t));
    assert(kr == KERN_SUCCESS);

    return tot_cpu;
}
```

You can fire a `Timer` let say 5 sec, on each tick you need to call the blow method. And when you find the point you want then post your notification or what ever you want to do.

```
- (void)checkCPUUsagesInEvery5Sec {

    if([self cpuUsages] > 10.0f) // your desire point
    {
         // your stuff
    }
}
```