# How to get CPU/memory/energy impact/disk/network info in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cpu-usage

when debugging app in Xcode, I can get these information(such as cpu,memory/energy..image here[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW9He.jpg)]) at debug navigator,how can i get these info in my app?Dose there have some OC/C api or function that I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS process internals - how to get information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595702/ios-process-internals-how-to-get-information)