# How to get total used memory

Tags: ios, swift

Can anyone help me get the total used memory of iPhone? I am working on an app to find all the details of iPhone. I have found 2-3 posts related to this question but they are either in Obj-C or a different language/syntaxsyntax. I have been working a lot to change the obj-c code to swift but got stuck somewhere down the path.

I am trying [Available memory for iPhone OS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798638/available-memory-for-iphone-os-app?noredirect=1&lq=1)
but everything looks different in Swift.

Also the syntax of mach is pretty much difficult. Can anybody provide some example with some explanation on it. I can get the all the information of the memory from here https://github.com/Shmoopi/iOS-System-Services/blob/master/System%20Services/Utilities/SSMemoryInfo.m
 But due to the copyright issue I can't use other's work. Also I don't understand anything from there.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. This will print out used memory in bytes.

```
var info = mach_task_basic_info()
var count = mach_msg_type_number_t(MemoryLayout<mach_task_basic_info>.size)/4

let kerr: kern_return_t = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &info) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: integer_t.self, capacity: 1) {
        task_info(mach_task_self_,
                  task_flavor_t(MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO),
                  $0,
                  &count)
    }
}

if kerr == KERN_SUCCESS {
    print("Memory in use (in bytes): \(info.resident_size)")
}
else {
    print("Error with task_info(): " +
        (String(cString: mach_error_string(kerr), encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) ?? "unknown error"))
}
```

Comment: I already came across the above solution but it only gives output as 30 mb. I think it's giving the memory usage of current application only. However, I need to get total memory used by all the application.

Comment: @Bikram How are you using this function. Here is a screen shot on a new project I just created with empty everything and just this function. I am printing out 276 MB right now. http://imgur.com/a/G21ic

Comment: @Ning ya that's right. But when I use other application to see memory usage then It shows me 1555.0 MB. I think 1555 MB is correct because iphone can't run on 276 MB only. Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 2):

@Bikram
 You can use below function to get total amount of memory used by system-

```
   func getUsedMemory() {
     var usedMemory: Int64 = 0
            let hostPort: mach_port_t = mach_host_self()
            var host_size: mach_msg_type_number_t = mach_msg_type_number_t(MemoryLayout<vm_statistics_data_t>.stride / MemoryLayout<integer_t>.stride)
            var pagesize:vm_size_t = 0
            host_page_size(hostPort, &pagesize)
            var vmStat: vm_statistics = vm_statistics_data_t()

            let status: kern_return_t = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &vmStat) {
                let boundPtr = $0.baseAddress?.bindMemory(to: Int32.self, capacity: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: vmStat) / MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride)
                return host_statistics(hostPort, HOST_VM_INFO, boundPtr, &host_size)
            }
            // Now take a look at what we got and compare it against KERN_SUCCESS
            if status == KERN_SUCCESS {
                usedMemory = (Int64)((vm_size_t)(vmStat.active_count + vmStat.inactive_count + vmStat.wire_count) * pagesize)
            }
            else {
              log("Failed to get Virtual memory inforor")
            }
   }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when using code: `Overlapping accesses to 'vmStat', but modification requires exclusive access; consider copying to a local variable` any ideas?

Comment: Foy anybody else getting the warning mentioned above. You need to create a local variable for the capacity, so `let capacity = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: vmStat) / MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride` and then in the `.bindMemory(to: Int32.self, capacity: capacity ).....`