# how to get the rate(top/ps) of cpu and the usage of memory?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Can i do that? or It's a private API?

Comment: I meant something just like taskmgr.exe in Windows System

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are not API's for this.

[How to display iPhone free memory ? and how to free iPhone memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563935/how-to-display-iphone-free-memory-and-how-to-free-iphone-memory)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the total memory usage of your app and total free memory in the system with the code posted in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921560/memory-troubles-with-uiimagepicker/2921725#2921725).

Of course, free memory varies depending on what background processes are running at the time and what's in the autorelease pool(s) at the moment, but it does give you some idea.